# Error while installing AllegroGraph on Arch Linux

Tags: allegrograph

I get the following error when running *install-agraph* for *agraph-6.6.0*

```
An unhandled error occurred during initialization:
Loading sys:aclissl.so failed with error:
/home/<username>/agraph-6.6.0/aclissl.so: undefined symbol: CRYPTO_set_locking_callback.
[physical pathname is /home/<username>/agraph-6.6.0/aclissl.so]
```

Cannot find much with google-fu on this error - at least nothing useful. Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: Installed on an Ubuntu system, works without problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been fixed in the upcoming 7.0 release of AllegroGraph.  Your workaround, using a system with OpenSSL 1.0.x is the correct one, for the currently released version of AllegroGraph.